# Should I use HiLo with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I am creating a ASP.NET MVC website where people can save their bookmarks. There is no limit on the number of bookmarks each user can store so the database tables may grow quite large.

Many to many relationship:

- A bookmark can have many tags
- A tag can have many bookmarks

My tables use identity to generate ids in a MSSQL database. When I insert a bookmark with NHibernate this results in multiple requests to the database. Up to 10 requests. I know there are alternatives to generate ids like HiLo, but I am not sure if I really need it.

This article suggests using HiLo in case of a greenfield application:

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/03/19/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.html

Questions:

- Should I use HiLo in my situation?
- Are there any disadvantages of using HiLo?
- In what situations are these multiple requests to the database going to hurt performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HiLo makes sense in scenarios where you have to batch insert lots of records constantly.

It is just easier for the client (NHibernate) to create the IDs on the client instead of 
having to query the database after each insert to get the new identifiers (which is more or less the case with auto increment Ids).

This should lead (also in your case) to better performance and less potential errors.

The downside is that you need another table to store the HiLo values and that other applications accessing the database all must know about that and need to implement the exact same logic. As long as your application is the only one accessing the database, this is not an issue.

In MSSQL2012 we now also have Sequences. This can be used instead of HiLo, the handling of IDs is more or less the same, you just have to create a sequence for each an every table...